# When integrate aws lambda with other services, Do they need to be in the same project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to use sqs with aws lambda, I create a new project for lambda(project A), and sqs code was written in another project(project B), what I want to do is, when some variables in B is calling sqs, it will trigger my lambda function in A, and do something, is that the correct way?
Or sqs and lambda must in the same project?

Comment: What is a "Project"? This is not a term usually associated with AWS.

Comment: like a java project contains sqs and lambda code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS is not aware of your code projects.

You can add configure Amazon SQS to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a message is pushed to the SQS queue. AWS does not know/care about how that configuration was set, or where the code came from.

Think of it like delivering a letter. The post office will deliver the letter to the indicated address. It does not know/care who *sent* the letter.